# Handle parsing empty file in NodeJS, Is it possible?

Tags: node.js, fs

I start with an empty file cart.json (just `touch cart.json`)

I have a default state for the file contents in my mind:

```js
const defaultCart = {
  products: [], // Array<{ id: string; quantity: number; }>
  totalPrice: 0
}
```

Now, when I read the contents for the very first time (remember the file has no content):

```js
const fs = require('fs');

exports.readCartDataFromFile = (cb) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, (error, fileData) => {
        const cart = {...defaultCart};
        if (!error) {
            const parsedFileData = JSON.parse(fileData); // throws error
            console.log('parsedFileData: ', parsedFileData);
            /* Do something with the parsedFileData */
        }
        cb(cart);
    });
}
```

I see this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/someusername/nodejs/main-app-altered/models/Cart.js:18:41
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:73:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

*The temporary solution is that I start the file cart.json with the defaultCart state so that I never come across this error.*

But, my question is - **Is there a way I could have determined (via some util in code) that the file has no contents so while initializing the model in the constructor, I write the defaultCart state into the file using fs.writeFile?**

Comment: Are you just looking to test if `fileData` is the empty string, i.e., `if(fileData == "") { ... }`?

Comment: It works, but I am not sure why.
When I console.log(fileData), I see <Buffer > in console

Comment: It looks like a buffer of length 0. I think a check for `fileData.length` would make sense for checking no file content. What do you think?

Comment: That makes sense! When you're testing for Buffer equality against strings, you need to account for encoding (how to the bytes of the Buffer map onto the characters of the string?) but in this case you want to test for no bytes at all, so it's much simpler `:)` I think testing for `length == 0` seems like a perfect approach.

Comment: Yo, thanks for helping out @apsillers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test for an empty `fileData` Buffer inside your read callback, you can just do

```
if(fileData.length == 0) { ... }
```

Or, if you want to catch any invalid JSON (including empty strings), you could nest your `parse` into a `try`:

```
try {
    const parsedFileData = JSON.parse(fileData);
    // ...
} catch(e) {
    console.err("Invalid JSON inside cart data file: ", e)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem like it should be much more complicated than this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const defaultCart = JSON.stringify({
  products: [], // Array<{ id: string; quantity: number; }>
  totalPrice: 0
});

exports.readCartDataFromFile = (cb) => {
  fs.readFile( filePath, 'utf8', (e, s) => {
    let err = e;
    let cart;

    if (!err) {
      try {
        const json = s.trim().length > 0 ? s : defaultCart ;

        cart = JSON.parse(json);

      } catch (error) {
        
        err = error;

      }
    }
    
    cb(err, cart);

  });
}
```

But if you want to create/initialize the file with default contents, then something like this would work:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');

async function ensureInitialized(filePath) {
  const fileInfo = await fs.stat( filePath ).catch(() => undefined);

  let initialized = fileInfo && fileInfo.size > 0;
  if ( !initialized ) {

    // if the file doesn't exist, or has a size of zero,
    // create/overwrite the default JSON to the file
    await fs.writeFile( filePath, defaultCart, {
      encoding: 'utf8',
      mode: 0o644,
      flag: 'w'
    });

    initialized = true;

  }

  return initialized;
}
const defaultCart = JSON.stringify({
  products: [],
  totalPrice: 0
});
```